# Determine the dominant asymptotic behavior of function

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, bessel-functions

The Bessel function $J_1$ is the bounded solution of the differential equation Bessel $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1)y=0$ at the point $0$ and gets the integral representation $$J_1(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\pi}^{\pi}e^{f(x\sin t-t)}\,dt, \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I want to determine the dominant asymptotic behavior of $J_1$ while $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ and while $x\rightarrow 0$.

$$$$

Could you give me a hint for that? Do we have to calcuate the limit of the absolute value of the funtion $J_1$  while $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ and while $x\rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: It is not given any further information about that. So is this not the general integral representation of the Bessel function $J_1$ ? @FranklinPezzutiDyer

Comment: I don’t know much about Bessel functions, but if I knew what the function $f$ was, I might be able to work out an asymptotic formula for that integral.

Comment: In general, how do we determine the asymptotic formula for that integral? @FranklinPezzutiDyer